# Intermittent sound

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, sound, thunderbolt

here is the problem I am dealing with. I run on Ubuntu 16.04, with a graphic card EVGA GEFORCE GTX 1070, and 2 screens. One of them is Dell, the other is Apple Thunderbolt (connected with Thunderbolt port with a Thunderbolt EX3 card). When I use only 1 screen (the Apple one), I am able to have sound from the Apple Thunderbolt speakers in the screen. However, when I display on my 2 screens at the same time, I can't have sound from the Thunderbolt screen.
Does anyone have an idea on what to look at to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Additional note. When I activate/deactivate sticky edges, I can have the sound from the screen (but not every single time, I know this sounds irrational).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to Bionic Beaver and NVIDIA 390 driver, solved the issue.